# missing a step ? what needs to be filled in the argument of loadLibrary()

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

These are the incomplete steps that i have followed to call a native function from a java program.

1. Wrote a java program and then compiled to the `.class` file
2. From the command `javah - jni` i generated a header file with the same name as `.class` file.
3. After that i opened a **Microsoft Visual C++ Express** , started a new project and set my application type to `dll`.

This is the java program that calls the native c method.

```
class HelloWorld {

private native void print();

public static void main( String args[] ) {
  new HelloWorld().print();
}

static {
  System.loadLibrary("??"); // what should i write here ?
}
```

}

**And this is the c program**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "HelloWorld.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL 
Java_HelloWorld_print( JNIEnv *env , jobject obj) {
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return;
}
```

I kept the project name as `jni tester` and the c file name is `HelloWorld.c`

In the statement `System.loadLibrary(??)` What should be the name of the library in the argument ? *(Or is there any step that i am missing before i can fill the argument of loadLibrary)*

If so what is that i am missing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From that function's documentation
[System.loadLibrary](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary(java.lang.String)):

> **Parameters:**
>
> libname - the name of the library.

You pass it the name of your DLL. (That is, the DLL's filename without the `.dll` extension. On Unix-like systems, it would be the shared object name without the `lib` prefix or the `.so` (or `.o` for some platforms) extension.)

Make sure your JVM can find the DLL in its library path. To change the library path, you can use the `java.library.path` system property like this:

```
java -Djava.library.path=directory_where_your_dll_resides ...
```

[Doing this and dropping the extension from the library name keeps the java side of your code as portable as possible. You'll be able to move it as-is to another platform, only needing to rebuild the JNI part for that target.]

Comment: you mean the name of project ?

Answer (score 4):

The library name is the name of the DLL file, without its .dll extension. The DLL must be in one of the directories of the windows PATH environment variable to be loaded.

Comment: I'm not sure dropping DLLs you're in the process of developing in the system's PATH directories is good practice.

Comment: During development, you set the PATH so that it contains the directory where the DLL is generated. Once in production, you deploy the DLL in some directory known to be in the PATH.

Comment: You might do that, but it's not to be recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the name of the library. You may omit the .dll extension, or you may include it.

If you specify just a filename with no path component, then the library search path will be used to search for the library.

Alternatively, you may prefer to specify the full path to the file which you can do. This latter approach is often preferable because it allows you to have precise control over where the library is loaded from.